# Geckodriver opening up only starting the application for the second time

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-debugging, geckodriver

I built a .NET WPF application which uses geckodriver. I installed geckodriver as a nuget package. On building the application on Release I got the bin>Release folder. I copy pasted that folder onto another PC and ran my application. Everytime I run the application on the first attempt geckodriver doesn't open up. Running the application for the 2nd time geckodriver opens up and works fine.
[image]

This is how my Release folder looks like.

1. How can I debug the Release version?
2. Why geckodriver not opening up at the first instance but only on second?

Would appreciate if someone could help out with this as I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: If your application is throwing an exception it might get caught under Windows `Event Viewer` -> `Windows Logs` -> `Application`. Is anything logger there when the app crashes first time around?

Comment: Does the blog about [How to debug and profile any EXE with Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-debug-and-profile-any-exe-with-visual-studio/) can help you to debug the Release version?